# Compose key in LXDE?

Tags: lxde, compose-key

I recently installed LXDE in Ubuntu 11.10, so that I can choose it at the login screen, but I've since noticed that there's no compose key (since I enabled it in Gnome Shell and Unity) so I was wondering how to enable a compose key?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`setxkbmap -option "compose:caps"` for CapsLock

`setxkbmap -option "compose:ralt"` for right alt =)

Comment: Hi, I did that for the right alt, but then I did it for the right ctrl instead, is there anyway to get rid of the one for the right alt, as now I can't use the Euro sign, as Alt gr doesn't work anymore, thanks :)

Comment: This [messes up other keys](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36315/why-does-the-setxkbmap-compose-key-mess-with-other-keys) on my machine.

Comment: This doesn't work for my with Lubuntu in a Virtualbox. Instead altgr opens up the context menu. Any further suggestions? How do I tell if the setting was correctly applied? How can I tell LXDE to unbind the menu behavior from AltGr?

Answer (score 8):

### To set the compose key

```
sudo leafpad /etc/default/keyboard
```

edit `XKBOPTIONS` to like this

```
XKBOPTIONS="compose:Shift+AltGr"
```

To get a list of available keys:

```
grep compose /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst
```

Reboot for the change to be applied or

```
setxkbmap -option "compose:Shift+AltGr"
```

To check if the option was set correctly

```
setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
```

### Example:

press Shift then AltGr and **release** then click on "o c" to obtain **©**.

### Additional reading

- [ArchLinux wiki - Keyboard configuration in Xorg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg)
- [Duncan Lock's blog - How to set your Compose Key on XFCE/Xubuntu Linux](http://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/05/03/how-to-set-your-compose-key-on-xfce-xubuntu-linux/)

Comment: Excellent answer! I might add that after editing `/etc/default/keyboard` a simple login/logout maneuver (which usually is enough when people say 'reboot') did not work for me (on Lubuntu 16.04). After a proper reboot it worked however!

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the keyscan code on your keyboard same as default setting.  Did you check if you can do the compose by selecting predefined keyboard with Compose key?

Answer (score 0):

For iBus, you can use

> setxkbmap -option "lv3:ralt_switch_multikey"

This is defined in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/` as "Right Alt [for 3rd level], Shift+Right Alt key is Compose"

This is also included when you select the `gb` layout:

> setxkbmap -layout gb